# Is possible to divide a long wraptable in two pages automatically?

Tags: tables, longtable, wrap

I have a text with a long `wraptable`. This table is long and fall over the last line of the page.

Here are the code and the result.

```
Di seguito vengono riportati alcuni esempi e applicazioni dei decibel tratti dalla vita quotidiana. La maggior parte di questi sono noti a chiunque abbia una scolarità elementare.

\subsection{Il pH}\index{Decibel!pH}
\begin{wraptable}{r}{7cm}
    \caption{Valori rappresentativi di pH}
    \label{tab:ph}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{Sostanza} & pH            \\ \midrule
        Acido cloridrico, 1 M        & \textless 1.0 \\
        Batteria acida               & 1.5           \\
        Succo gastrico               & $1.5\div2.0$     \\
        Succo di limone              & 2.4           \\
        Coca Cola                    & 2.5           \\
        Aceto                        & 2.9           \\
        Succo di arancia o mela      & 3.5           \\
        Birra                        & 4.5           \\
        Pioggia acida                & $\textless5.0$ \\
        Caffè                        & 5.0           \\
        Tè o pelle sana              & 5.5           \\
        Acqua deionizzata a 25 °C    & $5.0\div6.0$     \\
        Latte                        & 6.5           \\
        Acqua pura a 25 °C           & 7.0           \\
        Saliva umana normale         & $6.5\div7.4$     \\
        Sangue                       & $7.34\div7.45$   \\
        Acqua di mare                & $7.7\div8.3$     \\
        Sapone per le mani           & $9.0\div10.0$    \\
        Ammoniaca domestica          & 11.5          \\
        Varechina                    & 12.5          \\
        Soda caustica                & 13.5          \\
        Idrossido di sodio           & 13.9          \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}
In chimica il pH è un'unità di misura dell'acidità di una sostanza disciolta nell'acqua. L'acqua pura a 25 °C ha il cosiddetto valore di riferimento (detto di \textit{pH neutro}) fissato a 7.0. Soluzioni con pH minori di 7 si definiscono acide, mentre le soluzioni con pH superiori a 7 vengono definite basiche o alcaline.

Il pH viene definito come il logaritmo negativo dell'attività dello ione idrogeno in una soluzione acquosa\footnote{IUPAC Gold Book, ``pH''.}, vale a dire:
\begin{equation} \label{eq:ph}
    pH = - \log_{10}\left(a_H^+\right) = \log_{10}\left(\frac{1}{a_H^+}\right)
\end{equation}

Dove $a_H^+$ rappresenta l'attività adimensionale dei cationi ossonio $H_3 O^{+}$ , coincidenti con la concentrazione molare dei medesimi in soluzioni acquose sufficientemente diluite. Pertanto una definizione più frequentemente utilizzata della \eqref{eq:ph} è la seguente:
\begin{equation} \label{eq:ph2}
pH = - \log_{10}\left(H_3 O^{+}\right) = \log_{10}\left(\frac{1}{H_3 O^{+}}\right)
\end{equation}

Il pH---nell'esperienza quotidiana---assume valori tipici compresi tra 0 (acido forte) e 14 (base forte) come illustrato in Tabella~\ref{tab:ph}. Al valore intermedio di 7 corrisponde, come anticipato, la condizione di neutralità.

Volendo applicare rigorosamente la definizione si evince come il pH possa assumere tutti i valori compresi tra $\pm \infty$ in particolari soluzioni; ad esempio una soluzione di ``oleum'' (acido solforico concentrato saturato con triossido di zolfo) presenta un pH pari a $-13$.
```

[image: The result of the code]

I see that exists a `longtable` package, but I do not know how use it with `wraptable`.

Thanks to all,

Giacomo

Comment: If I use `\begin{longtable}` instead `\begin{tabular}`, I obtain the same result.

Comment: I don't if it's possible, but wouldn't it be as simple to have a single page table with 2 ×2 columns? By the way, there exists package that  ease typing correctly chemical formulae (`chemformula` or `mhchem`, for instance).

Comment: Try with longtable wihout wraptable.

Comment: @Fran, I know that it works, but I would like the text on the left of the table.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for your suggestion, but I have few chemical formulas. This is an example of the dB use in real life and mine is a text of telecommunications.

Comment: At least you should type your chemical formulae with `\mathrm`, in my opinion.  in $H_3O^+$, $H$ and $O$ are not variables. Same for pH.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni  I am afraid that we will need a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), not a chunck of the source code,  that illustrates exactly your problem, as well as a more precise description of what should be obtained instead.  If you need some amount of  text to reproduce the problem in the MWE, use as far as possible the package `lipsum` to add dummy text before or after the table with commands like`\lipsum[1-3]`, but please remove equations or any other code not related with the problem.